# How to use class type in transformer

Tags: c#, ravendb

In my `booking` object I keep an object reference list with the `Type` and `WorkflowStepTypeId` of the corresponding document. I then want to use the type in a `Where` to find the suitable document, and retrieve it by id. However, when compiling the transformer to `RavenDB` it says it doesn't know what my type is.

Code:

```
public class BookingToTrainingTransformer
        : RavenTransformerBase<Booking, BookingToTrainingTransformer.Result>
{
  public class Result
  {

  }

  public BookingToTrainingTransformer()
  {
      TransformResults = results =>
        from result in results
        let trainingWorkflow = LoadDocument<TrainingWorkflow>(result.WorkflowSteps
           .FirstOrDefault(a => a.WorkflowStepType == typeof(Trainingworkflow))
           .WorkflowStepTypeId)
   }
}
```

To clarify, I **know** that RavenDB wouldn't know what my type is. On the database side, I simply want it to make a string of both types and compare those strings. However, for refactoring purposes it would be great to know that the type is actually used in said transformer so if it ever gets refactored, the transformer also automatically gets refactored.

Is what I want possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want it to compare actual types so that if you refactor the type later, the transformer will still work?

No, that's not possible.

If I'm understanding your question right, can WorkflowStepType be a type name? If you refactor the type name later, sure, you'd still need to update the WorkflowStepType property in the database. But in your transformer, it'd just look like this:

```
.FirstOrDefault(a => a.WorkflowStepType == nameof(Trainingworkflow))
```

Comment: as said, I don't need RavenDB to do actual type comparison in the transformer. just a stringcomparison on the type names. It looks like nameof is what I'm looking for - weird that I never ran into it before. If the transformer compiles, I'll set the answer to solved :)